# How to Navigate to the Required Activity with some extra values inside pending intent Using FCM?

Tags: android, bundle, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Using FCM in my app. I can get the messages when my app is in foreground or background and I can also navigate to whatever page I want, but when I want to send some extra parameters to that activity, they are not reflecting and neither is the debug not firing in my activity after tapping the notification. I need to pass the extra values to my activity. Please help. The code is below:

My Listener class is

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   // @Override
/*public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
        String from = message.getFrom();
        Map data = message.getData();
    }*/




    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Object Oppname= ((ArrayMap) data).valueAt(1);
        Object moduleid= ((ArrayMap) data).valueAt(0);

        sendNotification(Oppname.toString(),moduleid.toString());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody,String Moduleid) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);


        String Category="";
        switch (Moduleid) {
            case "33":
                Category = "Category";
                break;
            case "34":
                Category = "sales";
                break;
            case "36":
                Category = "jobs";
                break;
            case "37":
                Category = "professional";
                break;
            case "38":
                Category = "sports";
                break;
            case "39":
                Category = "meetings";
                break;
            case "40":
                Category = "travel";
                break;
            case "41":
                Category = "realestate";
                break;
            case "42":
                Category = "banking";
                break;

            case "43":
                Category = "health";
                break;

        }

        intent.putExtra("Category",Category);
        intent.putExtra("PushType","");
        intent.putExtra("oppId","");
        intent.putExtra("chkboxType","chkboxlive");

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Right Place Right Time")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying that you don't manage to retrieve the extra parameters you put in the Intent from your Activity?

Comment: yes debug is also not firing inside that activity when i tapped on Notification@Michele Rullo

Comment: When you tap on the notification, does the Activity get launched?

Comment: Yes it is launched but i am unable to debug it

Comment: Try to clean your project on AndroidStudio, then restart the app, attach the debugger and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have tried but no result

Comment: Try to log in your activity (after tapping on the notification): Log.d("DEBUG", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Category"))

Comment: post your manifest please